# Dequeue always fails, queue is always empty

Tags: qt, qt4

I do not know what the heck is wrong with my code that it never Dequeus the queue, instead isEmpty always meets true.

```
class ConcurrentQueue
{
private:
QQueue<QByteArray> dataStore;

public:

void Enqueue(QByteArray value);
QByteArray Dequeue();

bool isEmpty();
private:
QMutex mutex;
};

void ConcurrentQueue::Enqueue(QByteArray value)
{
qDebug() << dataStore.length();
mutex.lock();
dataStore.enqueue(value);
mutex.unlock();
qDebug() << dataStore.length();
}

QByteArray ConcurrentQueue::Dequeue()
{

// mutex.lock();
// return dataStore.dequeue();
// mutex.unlock();

QByteArray tmp;

mutex.lock();

if(!dataStore.isEmpty())
{
tmp = dataStore.dequeue();
}

mutex.unlock();

return tmp;
}

bool ConcurrentQueue::isEmpty()
{
return dataStore.isEmpty();
}
```

next a timer is connected to a slot to Enqueu a packet every lt's say 10 milliseconds:

```
QByteArray built((char*)data, len) ;
//qDebug() << built.toHex();
qDebug() << "EnQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
queue.Enqueue(built);
```

A thread regularly checks if this queue is not empty it dequeues the queue and does something, but isEmplty always returns true

```
if(queue.isEmpty())
{
qDebug() << "#####################################";
return;
}
//NEVER COMES HERE
QByteArray rd15Bytes = queue.Dequeue();
```

here's the thread:

```
Write::Write()
{
}

void Write::run(){
while(1)
{
rs.writeToSerialPort(); // in this function above always isemplty is true

this->msleep(10);
}
}
```

Comment: as I run the code, queue size increases and the contents are enQd inside of it. but I wonder why isEmpty always meets !!!!

Comment: Are you sure you have only one ConcurrentQueue instance which you are using? Could it be that the instance which is always empty is different instance than the one that fills up?

Comment: yes, I am sure. there is only one instance of queue.

Comment: Are you _really_ sure? Have you checked the instance address values in debugger?

Comment: I tried your `ConcurrentQueue` class and it worked fine. But only after I fixed `QQueue dataStore;` to `QQueue<QByteArray> dataStore;` So the code you are running is different than the code in your question.

Comment: god, I don't know what you are talking about, I pasted above, the class defined is QQueue<QByteArray> dataStore; not simply QQueue dataStore. I have the same code here!

Comment: cmannett85 fixed your question formatting and generously fixed that too. If you look the original question, `<QByteArray>` is missing.

Comment: no man nothing was missed, i still get same results see this:

Comment: "020503" 
EnQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ 
#####################################  true 
#####################################  true 
#####################################  true 

enque is doen succesfuly, gives false for isempty. but when you call the queue from outside of the class, i mean with an instance, isempty returns true, always, this is my problem.

Comment: Then show more code. How the ConcurrentQueue instance is given and stored in the other thread? From the code you are showing I find it very probable that you are making a copy of the ConcurrentQueue instance for the thread, instead of using the same instance.

Comment: i dont' think you need more code than above. except that in the class header (RS), I included the ConcurrentQueue and 
    ConcurrentQueue queue_write;
    //ConcurrentQueue queue_read;

Comment: Well, _I_ don't need to see more code, but _you_ need to show more code if want to get help to get this fixed. How is the `queue` member variable defined in the thread? And how is it initialized?

Comment: well the RS is not a thread, is a class, I defined a variable of type concurrentQ queue_write or queue (i changed the name now), and the rest is what you see above. 
ConcurrentQueue queue_write;
what is happening? i think the isEmpty function I am using is not thread-safe , maybe, i don't know how to get isEmpty returning the same value inside RS as the correct value returned inside of its own class.

Comment: it is not initialized at all inside RS class.

Comment: a timer is run from MainWIndow to execute this slot, this enqs something to the queue. ok? 

`void RS::rs_plcDataAqustn(char* data, int len)

{
    
    QByteArray built((char*)data, len) ;
    
    qDebug() << built.toHex();
    
    qDebug() << "EnQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ";
    
    queue_write.Enqueue(built);
}`

Comment: next, another thread I mentioned above reqularly calls a function, inside that function i check if isemtpy is false then DeQ, but it never returns false.


`void RS::writeToSerialPort()
{
     if(queue_write.is_Empty())
    {
        qDebug() << "##################################### " << queue_write.is_Empty();

        return;
    } `

Comment: i hope it is clear now, (sorry I couldn't arragne the code in seprate lines)

Comment: So it seems that you have several different instances of the  ConcurrentQueue class. Do you know the difference between a class and an instance of a class? If not, I suggest that you learn that before writing more C++ code. You need to create only one instance of the ConcurrentQueue class and then give that instance to everyone that need to access the same data.

Comment: no man, you are wrong. We are now only dealing with the queue_write instance, the is not called. The other queue_read is called form another thread which I have not implemented yet. NOw, we are only talking about write. If I had used one thread for two instances of concurrentQ then what you say is correct. agree?

Comment: @Roku Just for the record I didn't add the template parameter in my edit, I just added the first code line into the code formatting region.  It appears that I did it because of this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45478/question-history-attributed-changes-to-me-that-i-didnt-make

Comment: I did not get answers yet.